# How to use substring in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to substring method in React native? I tried all methods which are given below but none of the method worked.

```
substring, slice, substr
```

Comment: have you tried substring?

Comment: I tried, it is crashing : TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Comment: the data you are applying substring to is undefined. did you verify that?

Comment: Again converted my string to string made me solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

The `substring` method is applied to a string object.

The `substring()` method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new substring.

This method extracts the characters in a string between "start" and "end", not including "end" itself.

If "start" is greater than "end", this method will swap the two arguments, meaning `str.substring(1, 4) == str.substring(4, 1)`.

If either "start" or "end" is less than 0, it is treated as if it were 0.

Note: The `substring()` method does not change the original string.

The way to use it is this:

```
var str = "Hello world!";

var res = str.substring(1, 4);

// res value is "ell"
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: It's generating an error which is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined.

Comment: RN is just a library in JavaScript, so standard JS should work as expected. Can you supply your code in context so we can see if there's something causing the error?

Comment: Probably you are referencing a undefined object. Check the variable you are trying to apply substring method is not undefined first

Answer (score 4):

You can use it :

1. ```
   var str = "Hello world!";
   var res = str.substring(0, 4); // output is Hello
   ```
2. if you get from JSON

   ```
   {item.name.substring(0, 4)}
   ```
3. from text

   ```
   this is text.substring(0, 5) // output is: this i
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1: *With Variables*

```
var str = "Demo String";
var res = str.substring(2, 5); //starts from 0
```

Method 2: *With States Directly*

```
<Text>{this.state.str.substring(0, 7)}</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

try 
`(obj.str).substring(1, 4);`

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23986290)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, you can make simple function. and then print in your jsx.

```
var number = "62857123456"

const slice = {
phone: (input: string = '') => {
let output = '';
// you can use substring, slice, substr
output = input.slice(2,14);
  return output;
  },
};
```

Finally, print on your jsx by calling the function that was created.

```
{slice.phone(number)}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same situation For this the solution is place all js code in a function and call it externally

```
class AboutMe extends Component {
    displayAboutMe(){   
        var data = this.props.getAboutMeQuery;
        if(data.loading){
            return(<div>Loading Books</div>)
        }else{
            var  aboutMe  = JSON.stringify(this.props.getAboutMeQuery.aboutme);
            console.log(aboutMe);
            var res = aboutMe.substring(12,453);
            console.log(res);
        }
    }
    render(){
        this.displayAboutMe()
        return (
            <div id="profile-section"></div>
          )}}
```